# Iterate over the "entrySet" instead of "keySet"

Tags: java

I'm scanning my code through SonarQube and it shows this code smell *"Iterate over the "entrySet" instead of "keySet""*. I tried, but I can't figure it out.

Sample code:

```java
public Set<Date> getAccountShiftDate(Map<String, Set<String>> shiftDatesMap, List<Groups> shiftSchedule) {

    // set that has the account shift dates 
    Set<Date> accountShiftDatesTemplate = new Hashset<>();

    // iterate on accounts
    for (String accounts : shiftDatesMap.keySet()) {
        //get group of an account
        Optional <Groups> shiftOptional = shiftList
                                             .stream()
                                             .filter(g -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(accounts,g.getLongName()))
                                             .findFirst();
        // ...
```

Can someone give me a reference to understand this.

Comment: What is the rest of your loop? I think you are hiding the crucial parts – do you somewhere call `shiftDatesMap.get(accounts)`?

Comment: shiftList hast no been declared in this part of the code - I feel like that might also be important

Comment: Yes, I do call that

Comment: On which map/line of code does it notify you? Could you indicate this with a comment in your code please.
Also do you understand the described code smell in general already? Sonarqube should be able to show you a description with good and bad example.

Comment: Is there something in SonarQube's description of the rule, https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2864, that you don't understand?

Comment: This question is incomplete. It does not include a [mre]. Please [edit] it to include the complete code required to reproduce the "problem". (The SonarQube rule should be pretty clear about it and even contain one compliant example and one non-compliant example)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785958/iterating-over-key-set-vs-iterating-over-entry-set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you iterate over `shiftDatesMap.keySet()` and later on call in your loop `shiftDatesMap.get(accounts)` you execute an unnecessary `get` operation for each entry.
Try to read an understand [the description of the metioned code smell](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2864) from SonarQube.

Instead you should use [`shiftDatesMap.entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) which gives you an Entry, i.e. as pair of the key and the value. So if you later on in your loop want to access the value for your given `accounts` key, you must only access the value from your entry, which is cheaper than calling a `get` operation on the map for each value.

Before:

```
for (String accounts : shiftDatesMap.keySet()) {
    Set<String> shiftDates = shiftDatesMap.get(accounts); // unnecessary operation
}
```

After:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry: shiftDatesMap.entrySet()) {
    String accounts = entry.getKey();
    Set<String> shiftDates = entry.getValue(); // access value for free without 'get' on map

}
```